# When i add rigidbody, animation makes player float. In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to play the animation but whenever i add rigidbody, player starts to float in the air at the constant value (which is 3.5 Y). No script is attachted atm.[image]

I tried to remove rigidbody which solved the problem, but i need it so deleting rb is not an option. Gravity values are normal and the other animations are from mixamo (i didn't do the animations).

Comment: Have you tried changing the RigidBody to kinematic? hard to say without seeing any of the details.

Comment: @Phillip long-term _kinematic_ rigid bodies defeats the purpose of a rigid body.

Comment: _"No script is attachted atm."_ - you don't need code to make things _move_. Do you have any design-time constraints added (via the Editor) to the game object?

Comment: Please post a listing/screenshot of other components attached to the object.

Comment: Normally this kind of problem is caused by root motion, which makes animation responsible to move the object, but in your case, the movement is happening only when adding it to the physics calculations, can you try to change your "update mode" in *animator controller* to "update physics"?

Comment: @MickyD Only defeats the purpose if you're using it for physics simulation, I use kinematic for plenty of things that need a rigid body for trigger interactions but are otherwise controlled by other means.

Comment: I changed to kinematics, it worked but it is not a optimal solution for me. No i didnt have any constraints on the character. I just find the solution but had to leave home so i couldn't reply early. apologies. thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i just solved the problem. Problem was neither rigidbody nor animation.
The collider of mesh (ground) has option checked "is Convex". I turned it off, problem solved, player is not floating anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information provided here is what I'm thinking:

The root cause of this is that your character model when effected by gravity is being pushed to the ground and foot IK is causing the legs to end up looking like your screenshot above.

Some common approaches to this problem:

1. Create an empty object called player (Controls Rigidbody/Capsule Collider/Character Logic)
2. Add the 3d Model as a child of this object (Animator/Mesh/etc).
3. On the root object add your rigidbody as well as a capsule collider (prevents character model from colliding with the environment due to gravity).

With this setup animations can be done on the model (+foot IK) without gravity causing issues.

Comment: Thank you. One question, whenever i create an empty object and add the model as a child, animations doesnt work properly. what i mean by properly is - the animation plays but it does not effects the position of the player, so it returns to initial position. Yes even tho i check the bake into position. Do you have any suggestions what to do about this.

Comment: Basically there are 2 common methods of movement - Root Motion which utilizes the animations and the root bone of the skeleton to determine movement.  (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html)... Non root motion movement is done by moving the capsule at that parent level, unity has a "character controller" which can work for this.  Here is an example of rigidbody movement as opposed to character controller : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html